# Xenomai: /dev/rtheap is missing

Tags: ubuntu, real-time, xenomai

I tried to install Xenomai 2.5.5.2 on my Ubunto 12.04 PC following the steps in [this guide](http://www.stanley.gatech.edu/skelly/uncategorized/installing-xenomai-on-ubuntu-12-04/#comment-3379).

I haven't changed any configuration options. When I run `sudo ./trivial-periodic`, I get a message saying

```
Xenomai: /dev/rtheap is missing
```

How can I resolve this error?